# Остановка процесса внутри контейнера Docker и выполнение команды

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch, контейнеры

Всем привет.
Суть в том, что у меня есть Докер контейнер с elasticsearch. Так уж вышло, что мне нужно выполнить команду по отвязке эластика от кластера, но для этого нужно остановить сам эластик.
Когда я выполняю остановку эластика внутри контейнера, то контейнер останавливатеся. Возможно ли остановить эластик и оставить контейнер запущенным?

Comment: Это русская версия stackoverflow, вопрос должен быть на русском языке

Comment: А в чем проблема запустить контейнер заново после остановки?

Comment: Так после старта и сервис внутри контейнера тоже стартует. А мне нужно, чтобы он был остановлен..

Comment: В ответе ниже вам все правильно написали, однако строго говоря если родительский процесс не сервис, который вам нужно остановить, то можно сделать то что вы хотите, однако это прям сомнительное решение. 
Например контейнер с supervisor который поднимает ваш сервис - одно из разрешений  вашей задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Прям то, что вы хотите, сделать нельзя.

Фундаментально, докер-контейнер это процесс, к которому применили некие настройки. Подключили файловую систему, ограничили права, создали свое пространство для идентификаторов пользователей/групп, номеров портов и т.п.

Поэтому когда главный процесс в докере остановлен, то и контейнер остановлен.

Можно обойти это создав новый образ основываясь на остановленном контейнере, а потом запустив новый контейнер используя новый образ.

Вот пример. Запускаем

```
docker run -ti ubuntu:latest /bin/sh -c "while true; do sleep 3; date >> /log; done"
```

Можно проверить из другой консоли (тут `2f93a0dc522f` это container id) что все работает:

```
$ docker exec -ti 2f93a0dc522f /bin/bash -c "tail -f /log"
Wed Apr 21 20:03:05 UTC 2021
Wed Apr 21 20:03:08 UTC 2021
```

Теперь если остановить контейнер, то и `exec` тоже остановится.

Теперь можно сделать комит:

```
docker commit 2f93a0dc522f xxx
```

И теперь запустить уже новый контейнер:

```
docker run -ti xxx /bin/bash
root@a67f1f72ac62:/# cat /log
Wed Apr 21 20:03:02 UTC 2021
Wed Apr 21 20:03:05 UTC 2021
```

Из этой консоли можно запускать нужную вам команду.

У вас, вполне возможно, данные или конфигурация хранится в volume-ах. Это значит вы запускали оригинальный `docker run` с volume-aми. Значит и новый контейнер нужно запускать с теми же volume-ами.